# Add cell with comment above table header and matching cell values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big data set, and after hiding some columns, I need to find some of the headers, depending on the cell value, and add a cell above each with the same header description and add a comment.

I did it with column index, but I realize that this data might have extra columns each time. I need a code to match a cell value and add on a row above the same value and add a comment to it

[image: Data example]

I tried this method, but it is not going to work all the time. for example next time I download he file, the colomn "Batch Management(Plant)" can be on row J

```
Sub Add_Row()

'First row with Comments

    Worksheets("MARC").Activate
    
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Batch Management(Plant)"
    Range("I1").Select
    Range("I1").AddComment
    Range("I1").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("I1").Comment.Text Text:="Calderon-Rabsey, Ana {PEP}:" & Chr(10) & "Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC"
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Plant-Sp.Matl Status"
    Range("J1").Select
    Range("J1").AddComment
    Range("J1").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("J1").Comment.Text Text:="Calderon-Rabsey, Ana {PEP}:" & Chr(10) & "For ZFIN, ZSFG, ZCNC After Costing this should show MA (Material Active)"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unit of issue"
    Range("O1").Select
    Range("O1").AddComment
    Range("O1").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("O1").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Calderon-Rabsey, Ana {PEP}:" & Chr(10) & "All ZFIN should be 'CS' (Cases)'Except for CO2 should be 'Blank'" _
    & Chr(10) & "All ZSFG ZCNC would be 'Blank'"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MRP Type"
    Range("P1").Select
    Range("P1").AddComment
    Range("P1").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("P1").Comment.Text Text:="Calderon-Rabsey, Ana {PEP}:" & Chr(10) & "ZFIN should be 'X0'" _
    & Chr(10) & "ZSFG with procurement type 'E' should be 'PD'" _
    & Chr(10) & "ZSFG with procurement type 'F' (kit components) should be 'ND'"
    Range("R1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.UsedRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175134)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Row1()
    Dim ColCnt As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("MARC")
        ' get the quantity of columns (include hidden columns)
        ColCnt = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ' insert row
        .Rows(1).Insert
        ' copy over header (only values)
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, ColCnt).Value = .Range("A2").Resize(1, ColCnt).Value
        ' loop through header
        For i = 1 To ColCnt
            With .Cells(1, i)
                If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                    .AddComment
                    .Comment.Text .Value
                    .Comment.Visible = False
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

- If you only need to copy specific columns and add comments, such as "Unit of issue" and "MRP Type", you can follow this approach.

```vb
Sub Add_Row2()
    Dim ColCnt As Long, i As Long, sVal As String
    Const COL_HEADER = "Unit of issue|MRP Type"
    With Worksheets("MARC")
        ' get the quantity of columns (include hidden columns)
        ColCnt = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ' insert row
        .Rows(1).Insert
        ' loop through header
        For i = 1 To ColCnt
            sVal = .Cells(2, i)
            If Len(sVal) > 0 And VBA.InStr(1, COL_HEADER, sVal, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                With .Cells(1, i)
                    .Value = sVal
                    .AddComment
                    .Comment.Text sVal
                    .Comment.Visible = False
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know where the column header is going to be next time I download the data. for Example MRP Type can be on column J but next time it can shift to column K. So I need to identify (probably with MATCH or FIND) where the the column is and then add a cell above with the same header and a comment (to new cell)

Comment: You don't need to `know where the column header`. Backup your file and try the code. Change `Const COL_HEADER = "Unit of issue|MRP Type"` to include all expected cols' header name.

Comment: I just run it again, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: how can I change the comments to another text depending on cell value? I tried For Each cell In rng

 "Select Case cell.Value Case Is = 'Batch Management' Target.AddComment' Target.comment.Text Text:="Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC End Select Next cell"
but it didn't add a comment on the Batch Management cell

Comment: What's `Target`? 
[What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)